vector valued Beurling Lax theorem
I am trying to solve the following exercise on vector valued Beurling Lax Theorem from Nikolski's book.

Something that is not clear to me is that in part (b), the author defines operators $\Theta : \mathbb T \to \mathcal{B} (D,F)$ by $(\Theta (\zeta ))(g) = g(\zeta)$ for each $\zeta \in \mathbb T$ and each $g \in D$. But functions $g$ are defined a.e. because it is $F$-valued $L^2$ function. How does the evaluation make sense?
